# using alarmmanager in a service to restart the same service after a period of time

Tags: android

i am creating an intent service in order to upload the data on the server. In this intent service, before making connection with the server i am checking if internet connection is available. if internet connection is available,then proceed else create an alarm (inside the service) to restart the same service at a later point of time.
my question is, whether this is a good practice or there is something else i should do in this case.

Comment: Why don't you just use a counter value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
{
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartServicePendingIntent);
}
```

Implement the onTaskRemoved method to know when your service is destroyed, and then creates an alarm to wake up your service.

Answer (score 0):

I'am Working on same! Here is My Code! 
Here I Made a Method Name as "set" to set Alarm

```
public static Boolean set(Context context, int Seconds) {
    mTime = Seconds;
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, AdReciver.class);
    mIntent.setAction(Constant.Actions.ALARM_ACTION);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, mRequesCode,
            mIntent, 0);
    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mCalendar.getTimeInMillis()
            + mTime * 1000, mPendingIntent);

    context.stopService(new Intent(context,AdService.class));
    return null;

}
```

Now You Have to Make a Alarm Reciver and Make an Entry in Menifest too for Register Broadcastreciver

In your Broadcast Reciver, You must have an onCreate method, White this Line to start service

```
context.startService(new Intent(context,MyService.class));
```

Maybe Its Help you! Let me know if you need more help.